# How do I display the result of the procedure Oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-xe

In my code there is a function that displays a message on the screen. But when I start, I do not see the result.

I guess this line does not work.

`UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET COMMISSION_PCT = NEWCOMMISSION WHERE LINES.COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL;`

Is it so?

I'm using Oracle XE 112, I'm using a browser.

Full code

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Zadacha31
IS
  lengthphone      INTEGER;
  substrcommission VARCHAR2(50);
  newcommission    FLOAT;
  info             FLOAT;
  CURSOR get_data IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   employees;
BEGIN
    FOR lines IN get_data LOOP
        IF lines.commission_pct IS NULL THEN
          lengthphone := Length(lines.phone_number);

          substrcommission := Substr(lines.phone_number, lengthphone - 1, 2);

          newcommission := To_number('.'
                                     ||substrcommission);

          UPDATE employees
          SET    commission_pct = newcommission
          WHERE  lines.commission_pct IS NULL;

          dbms_output.Put_line(lines.commission_pct);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

[image]

Comment: How are you calling the procedure and have you included `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I call the procedure like this
`BEGIN ZADACHA31(); END;`
I never did `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`, but `PUT_LINE` worked. Now I wanted to put `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before BEGIN, but got an error - ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an error in your logic.

Consider. You execute the UPDATE only if this test is true:

```
IF lines.commission_pct IS NULL THEN
```

Your code calculates a new commission and updates **all the records** (hint: this is probably not what you want but is irrelevant to your question).

```
UPDATE employees
SET    commission_pct = newcommission
WHERE  lines.commission_pct IS NULL;
```

However, your output is displaying the **unamended original value** and nothing else.

```
dbms_output.Put_line(lines.commission_pct);
```

So  your procuedure may well be updating and displaying something, but all it's displaying is a NULL so it looks as though nothing is occuring.

To solve this, use the new value:

```
dbms_output.Put_line('new commission = ' ||newcommission);
```

To solve the updating all records use a better where condition:

```
UPDATE employees e
SET    e.commission_pct = newcommission
WHERE  e.emp_id = lines.emp_id; -- or whatever the PK is
```

And why not make the output message more useful while we're at it?

```
dbms_output.Put_line('emp# '||  lines.emp_id||' new commission = ' ||newcommission);
```

Comment: You're right. I guessed that the problem would be with this line. Thanks for suggesting how to use the UPDATE SET WHERE clause correctly

Answer (score 2):

Try executing `set serveroutput on` before you run the procedure

Answer (score 1):

This is how it looks like in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Zadacha31
  2  IS
  3    lengthphone      INTEGER;
  4    substrcommission VARCHAR2(50);
  5    newcommission    FLOAT;
  6    info             FLOAT;
  7    CURSOR get_data IS
  8      SELECT *
  9      FROM   employees;
 10  BEGIN
 11      dbms_output.put_line('Procedure starts here');
 12      FOR lines IN get_data LOOP
 13          IF lines.commission_pct IS NULL THEN
 14            dbms_output.put_line('commision_pct IS NOT NULL!');
 15
 16            lengthphone := Length(lines.phone_number);
 17
 18            substrcommission := Substr(lines.phone_number, lengthphone - 1, 2);
 19
 20            newcommission := To_number('.'
 21                                       ||substrcommission);
 22
 23            UPDATE employees
 24            SET    commission_pct = newcommission
 25            WHERE  lines.commission_pct IS NULL;
 26
 27            dbms_output.Put_line(lines.commission_pct);
 28          END IF;
 29      END LOOP;
 30      dbms_output.put_line('Procedure ends here');
 31  END;
 32  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    zadacha31;
  3  end;
  4  /
Procedure starts here
Procedure ends here

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

It appears that the procedure finished correctly, but - nothing was displayed nor updated. Let's check why:

```
SQL> select count(*) from employees where commission_pct is null;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Does it ring a bell?

As of your environment: it looks like Apex' SQL Workshop, while data you use is contained in the HR schema. If that's so, you're right - you don't need to `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` there, it is enabled by default.

Though, that wasn't your problem, but the fact that no employee has `COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL`.